# Android MDM Document

Tags: android, document, device-admin

I have been looking for Android MDM documentation. 
[Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.htm) at this link there is little explanation. I want to develop MDM something like Mass360. And do some app restriction with my android app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You better go through [WSO2 EMM](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/Getting+Started) which will address your needs. Since this is free and open source you can extend this and make your own.